# How can i release the memory used by a datatable object

Tags: asp.net, datatable, garbage-collection, 3-tier

How can i release the memory used by a datatable object say dt; so that i can use it for a different set of values? is it enough dt=null;
is ther any advantage in doin this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`table.Clear();`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.clear.aspx) or less expensive simply `table = new  DataTable();`. Since `DataTable` implements `IDisposable` you could also call `table.Dispose();` or use it with a `using`-statement. However, that's not really necessary since a `DataTable` does not use unmanaged resources. It's just an in-memory object.

Side-note: you don't need to set it to `null` manually, the Garbage Collectior takes care of it, so there's really no need to do it.

[Setting Objects to Null/Nothing after use in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785/setting-objects-to-null-nothing-after-use-in-net)

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Shared Sub CleanupDataTable(ByRef dtToCleanup As DataTable)
  If dtToCleanup IsNot Nothing Then
    dtToCleanup.Rows.Clear()
    dtToCleanup.Constraints.Clear()
    dtToCleanup.ParentRelations.Clear()
    dtToCleanup.ChildRelations.Clear()
    dtToCleanup.PrimaryKey = Nothing
    dtToCleanup.Columns.Clear()

    dtToCleanup = Nothing
  End If
End Sub
```